# Async video processing in rails and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, resque

I'm using gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder', "0.6.2" for my video processing.

I simply need to write this code to have my video converted into many formats:

```
has_attached_file :video, :styles => {
  :mp4 => { :format => 'mp4', :convert_options => { :output => { :vcodec => 'libx264', :acodec => 'copy' } } },
  :ogg => { :format => 'ogg', :auto_rotate => true  },
  :webm => { :format => 'webm', :auto_rotate => true  },
  :flv => { :format => 'flv', :convert_options => { :output => { :ar => 44100 } }, :auto_rotate => true  },
  :thumb => { :geometry => "300x300#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 1, :auto_rotate => true }
}, :processors => [:transcoder]
```

But this code is synchronous and the user that upload the video is stuck during the conversion.

I would like to add an async wrapper (worker) around :transcoder so I can call:

```
has_attached_file :video, :styles => {... }, :processors => [:wrapper_transcoder_worker]
```

I have installed resque and redis and everything work.

Do you have an idea on how can I write the asynch worker around transcoder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lock paperclip at version 4.2.0

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Can you explain why this solves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [delayed_paperclip](https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/) gem? It pushes all processing into background and supports resque (among others).

Comment: Yes I tried and I got RoutingErrors during the loading of all my pictures in the public folder. I published an issue on the delayed_paperclip github: [link](https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/issues/132)
I only wanted to delay the processing of the video so I only added the option process_in_background on the video file and I got errors on pictures.

Comment: I hope our little discussion on Github helped the case ;)

Comment: Thanks katafrakt, I needed to lock paperclip at 4.2.0.